# Does calling chain functions yield an overhead?

Tags: java, c++, performance, method-chaining

Is there overhead in calling function chains?
For example, in the following for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  var=object.method1().method2().method3();
}
```

Is the first less efficient then the second?

```
var = object.method1().method2();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  var.method3();
}
```

My concern is to know wether there is overhead with function calling/returning, and not so much what the function does on the inside.

Thanks.

Comment: @RohitJain Of course not; he uses placeholder terms. The examples are perfectly clear though.

Comment: When you call a method an object, what usually happens is that the method is passed the 'this' pointer, as a hidden argument, this usually means either pushing it to the stack or saving it into a register. This value is simply used several times, when chaining, and hence no overhead occurs (atleast not after optimization). Do note that the compiler may actually save the 'this' returned by each call, if no optimization is enabled.

Comment: (Static analysis is required to ensure that you do actually return 'this', for the optimization to 'click').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two snippets are not functionally equivalent.

Your original question was tagged c++/Java so lets go with that.  A functional language might treat this differently.

In general the second version is quicker because the `method1().method2()` only needs to be called once. In C++ and Java the compiler has a really hard time figuring out if the calls `method1().method2()` has any side effects. Consider a method that takes user input for instance.

If the methods has side effects the compiler cannot do any optimizations to the number of calls in `var = object.m1().m2().m3()`.

The chaining itself does not produce any overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Considering its a pseudocode, second one should be faster, since you don't need `method1` and `method2` to be called for each iteration.

Comment: While true, I suspect this is not the *spirit* of the question.

Comment: @JohnDibling Yes, it seems like OP might want a low level explanation of how method invocation works and its performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [method cascading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading), you'd have this:

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object& Method1()
    {
        // do something
        return *this;
    }

    Object& Method2()
    {
        // do something
        return *this;
    }

    Object& Method3()
    {
        // do something
        return *this;
    }    
};
```

So calling the functions like this

```
obj.Method1().Method2().Method3();
```

Is functionally equivalent to

```
obj.Method1();
obj.Method2();
obj.Method3();
```

In short, there is no performance hit.  It is nothing more than a convenience idiom.  The one problem you face is that, since you are forced to return a reference to `this`, you cannot return something meaningful (e.g. the result of these functions).

If you are referring to [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining):

Each method must return some object that has the corresponding method that follows in the chain:

```
class Object
{
public:
    std::vector<int>& Method1()
    {
        // do something
        return _vec;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> _vec;
};
```

So calling

```
obj.Method1.size();
```

Is identical to calling

```
std::vector<int>& vec = obj.Method1();
vec.size();
```

So again, there is no performance hit.

However, if you were to change `Method1` to return by copy instead of by reference, it is possible to have a performance hit (e.g. if the vector is actually copied).

Though, I think you worded your question poorly.  Your second example has 2 less function calls per iteration, so yes, it will be more efficient than calling 3 functions per iteration.  But, I don't think that is really what you were asking about.

Comment: Sure, I was about to.  The explanation assumes far too much.  We really have no guarantee what any of those methods return.  We can't assume they just return *this, as we don't know the API for the object or anything else.  Perhaps it's three different objects?  Perhaps they live far from each other in physical memory and accessing them provokes a cache miss?  Perhaps there are side effects present any time you make a call to Metohd1().Method2().

Comment: @scriptocalypse Not really.  The methods must return *something*, and each something must have the corresponding method defined for the next item in the chain.  The way the question is structured, I assumed he was referring to method cascading (if not, I can edit the answer accordingly), but this answer is not incorrect, which is what a downvote typically represents.

Comment: Aaaah, if I misunderstand and the question explicitly refers to returning  *this then it does depend still on language and platform.  Assuming c++ and assuming that the functions have no side effects then you're correct.  Other platforms and languages aren't necessarily as performant though.  eg: Back when I was a Flash developer I would never have chained like that because of the terrible overhead present in function calls on the Flash player.  Even though this question is tagged as language-agnostic it probably can't actually be answered as such.

Comment: @scriptocalypse When I answered it, it was tagged as C++ and Java.  Both of those languages allow this type of behavior without a performance impact.  That isn't to say you cannot force a performance problem ... but the actual chaining isn't what would cause that.

Comment: Well that explains things, certainly.  I'd vote for the old tags to be reinstated then, as it's an important distinction to make.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how smart your compiler is, but assuming there is no special optimization happening on the compiler's behalf, in the example you listed you'd definitely be best off with your second example.  Pre-caching the return value of `object.method1().method2()' prior to your loop will absolutely save you time as you won't have to make those function calls or access those variables each time you iterate.

Calling a single method will have more overhead than simply accessing a local variable, and in your example you're calling two methods to access a single return value.

Comment: Both method1 and method2 might have side effects.

Comment: Absolutely true @Captain Giraffe.  Again though, it depends on language, platform, and compiler.  EG: using properties in C# on Unity appears to have no overhead compared to class-level field access when no side-effects are present in the property (truly just a get/set), while in Flash using properties would have all the overhead of a normal function call no matter the side effects..

Comment: @In this generic context I think we need to consider the possibility of a `thread.sleep(int_max)` in any of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, method1() and method2() are being called "n" times.  In the second example, method1() and method2() are only being called once.  If by "efficient" you mean "takes the least amount of time", then the second one is definitely more efficient.